# Analog of StringBuilder for BigDecimal

Tags: java, optimization, bigdecimal

I've got a list of BigDecimals to sum. If they were Strings to concatenate, I would use StringBuilder to reduce object creation. Is there something similar for BigDecimal? Or maybe I shouldn't bother about it? Is optimization of BigDecimal creation worth putting effort to it?

```
BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for (CashReportElement element : getReportElementSet()) {
    if (element.getCurrencyCode().equals(currencyCode)) {
        result = result.add(element.getSum());
    }
}
return result;
```

Comment: MutableBigDecimal is marked as fix for Commons Lang 3.0 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-276), but like most Commons projects, activity seems to have completely halted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The is no such analog in Java SE.

And on the question if its worth putting effort in it: You should look into this *only* if this code *has been proven* to be a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 7):

I'd cite Donald Knuth here:

> "We should forget about small
>   efficiencies, say about 97% of the
>   time: premature optimization is the
>   root of all evil."

Don't worry until it really is a measurable (!) problem. I'm not an expert for BigDecimal performance, but copying of char[] which is done during String concatenation is a much bigger overhead, that's for sure.