# BIgDecimal alternative like stringBuilder

Tags: bigdecimal

[Analog of StringBuilder for BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531377/analog-of-stringbuilder-for-bigdecimal)

I checked this link already but i am running sonar and it gives critical error for below lines:

```
.....
BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(0);

for (int loop = 0; loop <= 30; loop++) {
    switch (loop) {
        case 0: total.add(new BigDecimal(StringValue here)); break;
        case 1: total.add(new BigDecimal(stringValue here)); break;
        case 2: total.add(new BigDecimal(stringValue here)); break;
        //... and so on.
```

Any help how to resolve this error. Do I have to false positive this critical error as markerd by sonar.?

Answer (score 0):

`BigDecimals` are *immutable*. Therefore, `add()` is a method that returns a *new* `BigDecimal` with the desired value. Your code ignores the result, and `total` will not be changed, which means that your code, as-is, does nothing uesful. Do something like the following:

```
switch (loop)
{
    case 0: total = total.add(new BigDecimal(whatever)); break;
    // etc...
```